# Is the attractive Fermi-Hubbard model solvable by Bethe Ansatz?

Tags: condensed-matter, integrable-systems

I know that the one-dimension Fermi-Hubbard model is solvable by using the Bethe Ansatz method. The results I have seen, however, seem only to treat the repulsive case, i.e. $U > 0$, and I have not come across any discussion of the attractive case ($U < 0$). My question is: Can the attractive Fermi-Hubbard model also be solved by Bethe Ansatz?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, yes. The attractive case is addressed in chapter 16 (and references therein) of the Hubbard chain "bible": Essler, F. H., Frahm, H., Göhmann, F., Klümper, A., & Korepin, V. E. (2005). *The one-dimensional Hubbard model* (Cambridge). A draft of the book is available [here](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/%7Ekorepin/PDF_files/Hubbard.pdf), on Korepin's website. As the chapter describes, it is possible to solve the attractive model independently using Bethe ansatz methods, but it's also possible to construct a unitary transformation that reduces the attractive case to the repulsive one and use the solution of the repulsive model. A key paper on the latter approach is [F. Woynarovich, J. Phys. C: Solid State Phys. **16**, 6593 (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0022-3719/16/34/009).

Comment: Brief is good! Thank you, that's just what I was looking for.